# Code in heatwaveR bringing up error message "time must be given as character strings"

Tags: r

I'm trying to run some code from a vignette that is accessing the NOAA OISST data on the ERDDAP server (https://robwschlegel.github.io/heatwaveR/articles/OISST_preparation.html).
I have run this code numerous times before but for some reason I am now getting error messages.

The code I am running is the following:

```
# The packages we will need
# install.packages("dplyr")
# install.packages("lubridate")
# install.packages("ggplot2")
# install.packages("tidync")
# install.packages("doParallel")
# install.packages("rerddap")
# install.packages("plyr") # Note that this library should never be loaded, only installed

# The packages we will use
library(dplyr) # A staple for modern data management in R
library(lubridate) # Useful functions for dealing with dates
library(ggplot2) # The preferred library for data visualisation
library(tidync) # For easily dealing with NetCDF data
library(rerddap) # For easily downloading subsets of data
library(doParallel) # For parallel processing
```

```
# The information for the NOAA OISST data
rerddap::info(datasetid = "ncdcOisst21Agg_LonPM180", url = "https://coastwatch.pfeg.noaa.gov/erddap/")
```

```
# This function downloads and prepares data based on user provided start and end dates
OISST_sub_dl <- function(time_df){
  OISST_dat <- rerddap::griddap(datasetx = "ncdcOisst21Agg_LonPM180",
                                url = "https://coastwatch.pfeg.noaa.gov/erddap/", 
                                time = c(time_df$start, time_df$end), 
                                zlev = c(0, 0),
                                latitude = c(-40, -40),
                                longitude = c(15, 15),
                                fields = "sst")$data %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(time = base::as.Date(stringr::str_remove(time, "T12:00:00Z"))) %>% 
    dplyr::rename(t = time, temp = sst, lon = longitude, lat = latitude) %>% 
    dplyr::select(lon, lat, t, temp) %>% 
    stats::na.omit()
}
```

```
# Date download range by start and end dates per year
dl_years <- data.frame(date_index = 1:5,
                       start = as.Date(c("1982-01-01", "1990-01-01", 
                                         "1998-01-01", "2006-01-01", "2014-01-01")),
                       end = as.Date(c("1989-12-31", "1997-12-31", 
                                       "2005-12-31", "2013-12-31", "2019-12-31")))
```

```
# Download all of the data with one nested request
# The time this takes will vary greatly based on connection speed
base::system.time(
  OISST_data <- dl_years %>% 
    dplyr::group_by(date_index) %>% 
    dplyr::group_modify(~OISST_sub_dl(.x)) %>% 
    dplyr::ungroup() %>% 
    dplyr::select(lon, lat, t, temp)
) # 518 seconds, ~100 seconds per batch
```

At this final section of the code I get the following error message:
[1] "time must be given as character strings"
Error in print.default("you are passing ", paste0(class(dimargs$time))) :
invalid printing digits -2147483648
In addition: Warning message:
In print.default("you are passing ", paste0(class(dimargs$time))) :
NAs introduced by coercion
Called from: print.default("you are passing ", paste0(class(dimargs$time)))

Does anyone have any idea why I might be getting this error or how to overcome it?

I have tried updating R, the relevant packages etc. One other problem I have had which may or may not be relevant is that I don't seem to be able to install Rtools with the latest version of R (4.3.2)?

Comment: ```dimargs$time``` seems not to be a string. It has to be a string according to the error. Try running ```as.character(dimargs$time)``` and then re-running.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this but "as.character(dimargs$time)" isnt found. dimargs$time is not in the initial code, neither is print.default.

Comment: You'll note that on 23-01-2024, the [info page](https://robwschlegel.github.io/heatwaveR/articles/OISST_preparation.html)  was updated and now `as.Date()` has been omitted when creating dl_years. Other lines of code have been updated too.

Answer (score 0):

The code you tried to run used to work correctly, but now it needs a few changes. Also in the following example I have used a smaller temporal data range, but you can adjust accordingly. The problems were with using lon and lat instead of longitude and latitude. Also, dl_years, start and end dates need to be as.character(), and in the time_df function should use the sst_dataset1 with the associated info of the product instead of just the product's name.

```
    `# Get the dataset from RERDDAP ####
    sst_dataset1 <- "ncdcOisst21Agg_LonPM180"
    
    # Get info about that data set
    sst_info1 <- rerddap::info(sst_dataset1, URL = 'https://coastwatch.pfeg.noaa.gov/erddap/')
    sst_info1 `
    
    
    OISST_sub_dl <- function(time_df){
      OISST_dat <- rerddap::griddap(sst_info1,
                           url ="https://coastwatch.pfeg.noaa.gov/erddap/", 
                           time = c(time_df$start, time_df$end), 
                           zlev = c(0, 0),
                          latitude = c(-40, -40),
                          longitude = c(15, 15),
                           fields = "sst")$data %>% 
        dplyr:: mutate(time = as.Date(stringr::str_remove(time, "T00:00:00Z"))) %>% 
        dplyr::rename(t = time, temp = sst) %>% 
        dplyr::select(longitude, latitude, t, temp) %>% 
       stats:: na.omit()
    }

# Date download range by start and end dates per year
dl_years <- data.frame(date_index = 1:1,
                       start = as.character(c("1982-01-01")),
                       end = as.character(c("1989-12-31")))

system.time( OISST_data <- dl_years %>% group_by(date_index) %>% group_modify(~OISST_sub_dl(.x)) %>% ungroup() %>% select(longitude, latitude, t, temp))
```